# Textfield in SwiftUI doesn't work, I can't type in it anymore

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I have made a login view in SwiftUI and it worked at first but now that I have styled the view, my textfields don't work anymore. I can't type anything in the Textfields. Is this a Xcode bug or have I made a mistake. This is the code:

```
ZStack{
                Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack {
                    Image("login")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                        .offset(y: -50)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()

                    VStack {
                    
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "mail")
                            
                            TextField("Email", text: $email)

                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.top, 30)

                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "lock.rectangle")

                            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        }
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .zIndex(1)
                        
                        
                        Button(action: {login()}) {
                            Text("Sign in")
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100, height: 50)
                                .background(Color.red)
                                .cornerRadius(10)
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                                .padding(.top)
                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                        NavigationLink(destination: Register()) {
                            Text("No account? Sign up!")
                                .padding()
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .cornerRadius(35)
                                .padding(.horizontal)
                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6)
                    .background(RoundedCorners(color: .white, tl: 30, tr: 30, bl: 0, br: 0))
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .offset(y: 35)


                    
                }.shadow(radius: 15)
            }
```

The login button and register text do work so I don't think that there is an invisible object above the textfields.

[This is my design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OD81.png)

Comment: It works. Use only the HStack that contains the TextField to test.

Comment: But it doesn't work in the simulator. Would it work on a real device? or is there an invisible object blocking the textfield.

Comment: Did you test the TextField only?

Comment: Yes. in the register view all the TextFields work like it should. That makes it so weird.

Comment: could you add a screenshoot (design) of what you want to acomplish?

Comment: I have edited my question and added a screenshot of my design. In the register view the textfields do work thats the weird part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are using three views insid the `ZStack`. In other words you are laying three layers over the others. You should use 2 views inside the `Zstack`.

Second, use the `clipped()` modifier before `shadow()`.

```
        ZStack{
            Color.red
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .padding(.top, 20)
                .offset(y: -50)
                
                
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "mail")
                        TextField("Email", text: $email)
                        
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "lock.rectangle")
                        SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                    
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Text("Sign in")
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100, height: 50)
                            .background(Color.red)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                            .padding(.top)
                    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("hello")) {
                        Text("No account? Sign up!")
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(35)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6)
                .background(Color.white)
                .clipped()
                .shadow(radius: 15, x: 0, y: 0)
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
```

---

However, using the **ZStack** is unnecessary.

```
    VStack {
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "plus")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            .shadow(radius: 5)
            .padding(.top, 20)
            .offset(y: -50)
            
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "mail")
                    TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.top, 30)
                
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "lock.rectangle")
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                
                
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Sign in")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding(.top)
                }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("hello")) {
                    Text("No account? Sign up!")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .cornerRadius(35)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6)
            .background(Color.white)
            .clipped()
            .shadow(radius: 15, x: 0, y: 0)

        }
        .background(Color.red)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
```

---

You should use `.background(RoundedCorners(color: .white, tl: 30, tr: 30, bl: 0, br: 0))` adjust the offset of the innner `Vstack`.

Comment: This works! Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it. Also great tips!

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before. Usually it has just been an Xcode glitch and I have to quit and restart the IDE a couple times before it actually shows up. However in Simulator it works. Hope it's resolved now though! :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).